# Change title of phone when connected to Windows PC

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I inherited my Samsung Galaxy S4 phone from the employee who preceded me in my current position.

When I connect the phone to my Windows 7 laptop, it displays in Devices and Printers with a name matching that of the former employee.

There are none of his accounts left on the phone.

The phone is running Android 4.3.

How do I change the name of the phone I see in Devices and Printers?

**UPDATE**: I think this name is a Windows setting.  I think I was seeing an old title, from when the phone had accounts belonging to the other employee.

There was another device under Devices & Printers called Galaxy S4.

I right-clicked on the device with the old employee's name, clicked uninstall.

When I disconnect and reconnect my phone I no longer see a device with the old employee's name, but I do see "Galaxy S4".

Comment: Did you just edit an answer in your question? Move that answer as a separate answer, and accept it as an answer two days later. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this name is a Windows setting. I think I was seeing an old title, from when the phone had accounts belonging to the other employee.

There was another device under Devices & Printers called Galaxy S4.

I right-clicked on the device with the old employee's name, clicked uninstall.

When I disconnect and reconnect my phone I no longer see a device with the old employee's name, but I do see "Galaxy S4".